# Android USB drive for windowS installing problems

Tags: android, installation, unity-game-engine, tablet, usb-drive

I recently bought a tablet from a company, in order to test my Unity3d games in a real android device. The problem is, the company did not provide the android USB windows drive to be installed and if I`m not wrong it is necessary to make the debugging process work (please correct me if I`m wrong). After some calls and emails for the technical support of this company, they provided me with files, which they are saying it`s what I need.

I have no idea of what to do with these files. Actually I`m thinking they are being dishonest with me and just gave me some random files. So if someone here could just check these files and see if they are actually drive files, or something else.

Just to be clear, I trying to get this drive because, when plug my tablet in my computer (with debugging mode enabled), and check in the Devices and Printers, I see a device called android, with no drive installation and information. Unity3d also can`t find any eligible android devices plugged on my computer.

I also already tried to install manually this “drive” they gave me using the UpdateDrive option, search for a drive in a computer folder.

If these are real drive files, could someone explain me how to install it on my windows 8?

Here is the link :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rqwzahpswk91lc9/WV5gvcPawx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the SDK manager and select "Google USB Driver" to install.

I run at the same problem with a prototype device, the company give the drivers to me and even I can install it, the SDK don't recignize the device in debug mode.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

EDIT:
Even the Google says that the "Google USB Drivers" is for Nexus devices, it solved my problem with a Honeywell device.

EDIT2:
Can you post the file extensions if this doesn't work?
There is a .inf file?
If yes, you can install it just opening the 'Device Manager' in System properties (Win + Pause/Break) -> Select the usb device, double click on it -> Select update the driver -> select to install from disk -> select the .inf file.

Comment: Hey borgo, thanks for all your replays. Look I already opened my android manager and checked if the Google USB Driver was already downloaded and it was already installed. In fact, before this tablet I had a Nexus S, so I need this “Google USB Driver” installed previously.  

With my question, I post a link from a dropbox folder, which contains the files the company gave me. There is an .inf as you said. However, after had done the process you just described I receive the follow windows message:

Comment: Windows could not find driver sofware for your diveice

Comment: I`m going to upload an image file, in the same dropbox folder, with this error message

Comment: sorry, I'm working now and in my company the proxy block the dropbox link :( too bad.

Comment: But, like you say, if it have the .inf, maybe it's from an old version of windows or from a diferent device, try to contact the company again and report the error.

Comment: Thanks Borgo, I will do it tomorrow anyway, but I don`t think they know what I really need. That is the third time they send this useless files.

Answer (score 0):

If you can plug into a Linux then do lsusb in a linux terminal. Take that code and search the Internet. Might be the tablet you bought uses a common chipset and you can install the android driver from another vendor. You need the drivers based on the manufacturer. E.g. to debug with Android for samsung then install their Kies, for Motorola then their android drivers. Note, "Android drivers" is in addition to the regular usb driver than lets the phone show up as a disk drive.

Comment: Thanks for you replay codeslapper, look I will download and install virtualBox in order to have a linux machine here. But, would I be able to pick whatever this command you said find on internet, and bring/install it on my windows ?

Comment: It`s because there is no Unity3d for Linux OS, so it be must work on my windows...